# How to produce subscripted SVG text consistently across browsers?

Tags: css, svg

I need to produce SVG text with subscripts, but I'm having a hard time getting consistent results across browsers.

For example, this SVG ([jsFiddle](http://goo.gl/jFYJRX)) produces different results in different browsers.  With Chrome 31, for example, the opening and closing parentheses line up vertically, but not so with Firefox 25 and IE 11.

```
.legend{
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier, monospace;
  font-size:13px;
}

.subscript{font-size:smaller;}
<svg width="60" height="30">
  <g transform="translate(20, 25)">
    <text class="legend">
      <tspan                                dy="-1ex">(</tspan>
      <tspan class="subscript" dx="-1.25ex" dy="+1ex">0</tspan>
      <tspan                   dx="-1ex"    dy="-1ex">)</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image: misaligned parentheses, zoomed in]

How can I get consistent results across browsers?

(FWIW, I'm using d3.js to generate the SVG code to do this.)

Comment: You should include sample code, showing what you have tried, in the question itself.

Comment: Have you tried using [`baseline-shift`](http://www.svgbasics.com/font_effects_italic.html)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: [FF does not supported it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=308338); AFAICT, IE doesn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kjo, you already found an answer, but this also works for me (see below for "me"):

```
<svg width="60" height="30">
    <g transform="translate(20, 25)">
        <text class="legend">
            <tspan dy="-1ex">(</tspan>
            <tspan dx="-1ex" dy="+1ex"><tspan class="subscript">0</tspan></tspan>
            <tspan dx="-1ex" dy="-1ex">)</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Result:

[image: better aligned]

-- it seems the size inside the `tspan` is relative to the size of the text *in that same span*. (I decreased the text offset from `-1.25ex` to `-1ex` to get the same visual distance for the '0'.)

"Me" is Safari 6.0.4 on OSX 10.7.5, and the parentheses appear misaligned with your original SVG but not with mine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way to achieve the desired effect is to use pixels rather than `ex`/`em` units for the offset parameters.

E.g., this is passable:

```
<svg width="60" height="30">
  <g transform="translate(20, 20)">
    <text class="legend">
      <tspan                   dy="-0px">(</tspan>
      <tspan class="subscript" dy="+5px">0</tspan>
      <tspan                   dy="-5px">)</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

(where the `subscript` class has `font-size:smaller` in its CSS).

This means, of course, that changing font sizes requires changing these vertical offsets.  The only solution I can come up for this is to set all these values programmatically, and maybe also use `px` rather than `pt` for font sizes.  Then one can programmatically set the pixels for the vertical offsets as a certain multiplier of the font size.

Comment: Was just going to suggest that: "As in CSS, the em and ex unit identifiers are relative to the current font's font-size and x-height, respectively." (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html) Note that `pt` *should* be okay as well, it's also an absolute measurement unit.